# Controlling arduino over webserver

Tags: ethernet

I want to control arduino through Internet without using Ethernet shield. I know there is a way. So can you help me what things I'll be needing for that

Comment: `I know there is a way.` - what is this way of which you speak?

Comment: I don't want to use Ethernet shield

Comment: Well, what _do_ you want to use?

Comment: I want to control lights through wamp server

Comment: Ah, great! Go down to the corner store and buy yourself a WAMP server.

Comment: I have a wamp server running in my system.. So how can I connect using php script

Comment: Your question - both of them - is really too vague to answer in any but a vague way. Say more about what you _do_ want to do. You need to connect to the internet in _some_ way; what ways _will_ you consider? You've mentioned "a wamp server running in my system" - what system, and how do you intend for it to participate in this project? There's really not enough here for anyone to be able to offer much help.

Answer (score 3):

This is incredibly broad: you could use an Arduino Ethernet, which has built in Ethernet, or you could use an ENC28J60 Ethernet module, or any of the many, many WiFi peripherals.

Also, consider using the ESP8266, instead of an Arduino with an Ethernet/WiFi peripheral. The ESP8266 can be programmed directly from the Arduino IDE with Arduino-style syntax, and can also run the NodeMCU firmware (programmed in Lua).